# How do I access app classes after using namespace?

Tags: php, namespaces, laravel

I have a class in `models/Model.php` that looks like this:

```
namespace Foobar;

class Auth {
    // check if user is logged in
    public function isLoggedIn() {
        return Session::has('user');
    }
}
```

I use this class from my controller with:

```
$foo = new Foobar\Auth();
var_dump($foo ->isLoggedIn());
```

The problem is that now `Session` isn't available. I get the following error message:
`Class 'Foobar\Session' not found`

How do I make Laravel's `Session` available in my class after using a `namespace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 1: import it

```
namespace ...;
use Session;

Session::foo();
```

Option 2: specify the absolute namespace path to the `Session` class

```
\Session::foo();
```